# Equivalent definitions of Injective Banach Spaces

Tags: banach-spaces

A Banach space $X$ is said to be injective if for all Banach spaces $W,Z$  with $W\subset Z$, and operators $T\in B(W,X)$, $T$ can be extended to all of $Z$ with the same norm.

Equivalently, $X$ is injective if it is complemented by a norm $1$ projection in any Banach space containing it.

---

Labelling the first definition as $(1)$ and the second definition as $(2)$, the proof for $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$ is brief.

If $X\subset Y$ for some Banach space $Y$, then applying $(1)$ to the identity map on $X$ yields the projection.

---

The $(2)\Rightarrow (1)$ direction I have been stuck on for a couple of days.  Can anyone offer a hint?  Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: I think you have a typo reflexive -> injective in the first sentence?

Comment: That was an egregious error.  Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can isometrically embed $X$ into $\ell^\infty(\Gamma)$ where $\Gamma$ is some humongous set of indices (e.g., take every point of the unit ball of $X^*$ as an index).

Given $T:W\to X$, think of it as $T:W\to \ell^\infty(\Gamma)$ and extend it to $\widetilde T: Z\to \ell^\infty(\Gamma)$ preserving the norm (the special form of the norm on $\ell^\infty(\Gamma)$ will help.) Then do the obvious thing.

Comment: Thanks!  I will give this a shot.  I kept trying to embed $X$ into some sort of direct sum, but it never went anywhere.

Comment: Got it, just take $P\circ\tilde{T}$ as the extension, where $P$ is the projection which exists by assumption.  Thanks!

Yes after typing our my first response I immediately realized that it made no sense.